# 4k@60hz on MBP mid 2015 (intel iris 1536 only) HOW?

Tags: mac, displayport, 4k

Right now i can only do 4k@30hz through the hdmi port.
I get "No Signal" when i connect using a mDP to DP cable on the same monitor.

What steps would I take to get 60 Hz @ 4K display?

Comment: I run a Dell 4k monitor on a 2015 15" with integrated graphics using a mDP to DP cable.  Is yours a 13" or a 15"

Comment: Actually it made me even more anxious since i definitely saw that my MBP can do 4k@60hz over there on that lookup site...but mine for some reason doesn't want to. Maybe it's the cable, but the one i bought, specifically says it's for 4k@60hz. I really don't know what other trick i can do to make it work.

Comment: It's a 15'' MBP

Comment: Another interesting info to add is: 2years ago i used the thunderbolt ports on this same MBP with a mDP to DVI (or mDP to DP cable i can't remember) on a 1080@60hz monitor, no problems whatsoever.

Comment: If some of the information from the comments goes into the body of the question, we might be able to vote to reopen if it’s not a duplicate of our general question. Without details of the hardware clearly stated, it’s best to point to the FAQ to get started

Comment: These are my specs. It clearly states that it can run 4k@60hz.
https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.2-15-iris-only-mid-2015-retina-display-specs.html#macspecs1

Comment: @ppomega That site says that the computer can run 1080p@60Hz, 3840x2160@30Hz, and 4096x2160@24Hz

Comment: I think that part where it talks about 3840x2160@30Hz is for the HDMI port, which is true. The thunderbolt port is what I'm interested in. Why am i getting "no signal"? I just want to get any kind of a signal from the thunderbolt ports at the moment.

Comment: update: i just bought a mDP to HDMI adapter and the mDP port woke up!!! But sadly it only outputs 1080p @60hz
This tells me that probably i need an ultra awesome mDP to DP cable to get something out of my MBP